# How to add files in directory of azure through java service?

Tags: java, spring, api, azure

I am creating application where I want to store folder from local storage(from PC) to directory created under any share of azure. I am working under 'file' of azure's storage account.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
    public String uploadDirectory(JSONObject jsonInput) throws IOException {
        CloudFileClient fileClient = null;
        try{
        fileClient = FileClientProvider.getFileClientReference();
        String directoryLocation = jsonInput.get("directoryLocation").toString();
        File f = new File(directoryLocation);
        listFilesForFolder(f);

        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference(f.getName().toLowerCase().replace(".", "").replace("_", ""));
        if (share.createIfNotExists()) {
            System.out.println("New share created");
        }
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(f.getName().toLowerCase().replace(".", "").replace("_", ""));
        if (sampleDir.createIfNotExists()) {
            System.out.println("new directory created");
        } 
        for ( ListFileItem fileItem : rootDir.listFilesAndDirectories() ) {
            System.out.println(fileItem.getUri());
        }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception "+e);
        }
        return "Check";
    }
```

How can I store all folder 'f' and it's contents to directory 'sampleDir' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following sample code to upload your local folder and its contents to Azure file storage in your application.

```
@Override
public String uploadDirectory(JSONObject jsonInput) throws IOException {
    CloudFileClient fileClient = null;
    try {
        fileClient = FileClientProvider.getFileClientReference();
        String directoryLocation = jsonInput.get("directoryLocation").toString();
        File f = new File(directoryLocation);

        CloudFileShare share = 
        fileClient.getShareReference(f.getName().toLowerCase().replace(".", "").replace("_", ""));
        if (share.createIfNotExists()) {
            System.out.println("New share created");
        }
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

        listFilesAndUploadToCloud(f.getAbsolutePath(), rootDir);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }
    return "Check";
} 

public void listFilesAndUploadToCloud(String filePath, CloudFileDirectory storageDir) throws Exception {

    File f = new File(filePath);
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            CloudFile cloudFile = storageDir.getFileReference(file.getName());
            cloudFile.uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            CloudFileDirectory cloudDir = storageDir.getDirectoryReference(file.getName());
            if (cloudDir.createIfNotExists()) {
                listFilesAndUploadToCloud(file.getAbsolutePath(), cloudDir);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.Good logic and well implementation.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at this question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450473/how-to-download-file-having-spaces-in-its-name-from-azure-by-java-service

Comment: I'm trying to find maximum size of file can upload from java? with above API @Deva